# Various Errors When Booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot

After booting, the following message appears:

```
Welcome to emergency mode after logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot systemctl default Use "systemctl default" or ^D to activate default mode.
```

I try ^ D but appears another error message, something like I did not have authorization:

```
Error Getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: no surch file directory( g-io-error-quark, 1)
```

What to do to solve this, and be able to boot normally?